# After git rebase: I found another detached master branch

Tags: git

Recently i wanted to do some changes to a file in the FIRST COMMIT(c37a5b9) (browse down to see the git log)

So i did:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

It opened a vim editor showing all the commits.Then I chose the FIRST COMMIT(c37a5b9) to edit and closed it.
then edited some file and then did

```
git add -A
```

then did

```
git rebase --continue
```

I had some conflicts with the SEVENTH COMMIT. I manually resolved it by editing the conflicts.

Then did

```
git add -A
```

then again

```
git rebase --continue
```

And after this i found this tree.

```
* da348ec - Sat, 12 Oct 2019 07:55:40 +0530 (4 hours ago) (HEAD -> master)
|           NINTH COMMIT 
* e507db5 - Thu, 12 Sep 2019 13:46:42 -0400 (4 weeks ago)
|           EIGHT COMMIT
* 541e199 - Mon, 9 Sep 2019 12:46:00 -0400 (5 weeks ago)
|           SEVENTH COMMIT
* dbe3979 - Thu, 11 Jul 2019 06:04:58 -0400 (3 months ago)
|           SIXTH COMMIT
* b98d381 - Mon, 22 Apr 2019 15:42:42 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           FIFTH COMMIT
* b24c5f0 - Fri, 12 Apr 2019 12:29:31 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           FOURTH COMMIT
* 1c9341d - Fri, 12 Apr 2019 00:23:24 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           Third Commit
* cc193e6 - Tue, 9 Apr 2019 00:37:25 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           Second Commit
* 6592e2c - Mon, 8 Apr 2019 23:59:24 +0530 (6 months ago)
            First Commit

* 2229bec - Tue, 24 Sep 2019 07:12:44 -0400 (3 weeks ago) (origin/backup_of_login_with_database, backup_of_login_with_database)
|           NINTH COMMIT (not used procedure)
| *-.   e708887 - Tue, 24 Sep 2019 13:47:56 -0400 (3 weeks ago) (refs/stash)
| |\ \            WIP on master
|/ / /  
| | * 4cd7f19 - Tue, 24 Sep 2019 13:47:56 -0400 (3 weeks ago)
| |             untracked files on master
| * 159e63a - Tue, 24 Sep 2019 13:47:56 -0400 (3 weeks ago)
|/            index on master
* 9ad7f9a - Thu, 12 Sep 2019 13:46:42 -0400 (4 weeks ago) (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
|           EIGHT COMMIT
* 9a50dde - Mon, 9 Sep 2019 12:46:00 -0400 (5 weeks ago)
|           SEVENTH COMMIT
* 5c786a8 - Thu, 11 Jul 2019 06:04:58 -0400 (3 months ago)
|           SIXTH COMMIT
* c7ca76f - Mon, 22 Apr 2019 15:42:42 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           FIFTH COMMIT
* eb1ca3c - Fri, 12 Apr 2019 12:29:31 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           FOURTH COMMIT
* a652e6e - Fri, 12 Apr 2019 00:23:24 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           Third Commit
* 27cc974 - Tue, 9 Apr 2019 00:37:25 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           Second Commit
* c37a5b9 - Mon, 8 Apr 2019 23:59:24 +0530 (6 months ago)
            First Commit
```

6592e2c and c37a5b9 are two FIRST COMMITS i see. I see two master branches.

I was confused.

The below is what i had before i started the rebase. So how can i change a file of FIRST COMMIT with the below git log.

```
* 54a7170 - Sat, 12 Oct 2019 07:55:40 +0530 (4 hours ago) (HEAD -> master)
|           NINTH COMMIT 
* aa6dfe6 - Thu, 12 Sep 2019 13:46:42 -0400 (4 weeks ago)
|           EIGHT COMMIT
| * 2229bec - Tue, 24 Sep 2019 07:12:44 -0400 (3 weeks ago) (origin/backup_of_login_with_database, backup_of_login_with_database)
| |           NINTH COMMIT (not used procedure)
| | *-.   e708887 - Tue, 24 Sep 2019 13:47:56 -0400 (3 weeks ago) (refs/stash)
| | |\ \            WIP on master
| |/ / /  
| | | * 4cd7f19 - Tue, 24 Sep 2019 13:47:56 -0400 (3 weeks ago)
| | |             untracked files on master
| | * 159e63a - Tue, 24 Sep 2019 13:47:56 -0400 (3 weeks ago)
| |/            index on master
| * 9ad7f9a - Thu, 12 Sep 2019 13:46:42 -0400 (4 weeks ago) (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
|/            EIGHT COMMIT
* 9a50dde - Mon, 9 Sep 2019 12:46:00 -0400 (5 weeks ago)
|           SEVENTH COMMIT
* 5c786a8 - Thu, 11 Jul 2019 06:04:58 -0400 (3 months ago)
|           SIXTH COMMIT
* c7ca76f - Mon, 22 Apr 2019 15:42:42 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           FIFTH COMMIT
* eb1ca3c - Fri, 12 Apr 2019 12:29:31 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           FOURTH COMMIT
* a652e6e - Fri, 12 Apr 2019 00:23:24 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           Third Commit
* 27cc974 - Tue, 9 Apr 2019 00:37:25 +0530 (6 months ago)
|           Second Commit
* c37a5b9 - Mon, 8 Apr 2019 23:59:24 +0530 (6 months ago)
            First Commit
```

I will later do `push -f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are all keeping your old version of `master` alive.

- The remote-tracking branch `origin/master`
- The local branch `backup_of_login_with_database`
- The remote-tracking branch `origin/backup_of_login_with_database`
- Work in progress stashed against the old `master`

When you `git push --force origin master`, `origin/master` will reflect the rewritten history.

You can throw away the stashed commit with `git stash drop` or resume the WIP with `git stash apply`.

Transplant `backup_of_login_with_database` to the new history with

```
git rebase --onto master~ backup_of_login_with_database~ backup_of_login_with_database
```

or, using SHA1 object names that are specific to the history you showed

```
git rebase --onto e507db5 9ad7f9a backup_of_login_with_database
```

Also force-push that branch with

```
git push --force origin backup_of_login_with_database
```

All that said, consider whether all the above trouble is really worth it versus merely making the change on top of the `master` and `backup_of_login_with_database` branches.

Comment: I will check this and come back

Comment: Eight commit is the parent for `backup_of_login_with_database`. When i modified First commit i expect the branch also to automatically change. Rather it gets separated. Why is that

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi You performed your rebase on the master branch, so it left backup_of_login_with_database (and all other branches) alone.

Comment: Assuming i change the "FIFTH COMMIT" commit, its common to both the  master and backup_of_login_with_database. Still after rebase it splits master separate. I am expecting if i change FIFTH COMMIT both the branches should automatically adjust

Comment: My main purpose of doing rebase is to edit a commit. After see this if i change a commit using rebase then after than i have to do `rebase --onto` again to club the branch with the master.

Comment: Are detached branches allowed in git. I was thinking ny branch should be connected with master. Generally git log does not show detached commits. So why its showing the detached branch

Comment: `master~` and `backup_of_login_with_database~` means

Answer (score 0):

When using `git rebase -i --root`, choose the first commit would rewrite the whole commit history of local master. So, after the rebase, you got the local master branch started with `6592e2c` and remote master with the original `c37a5b9`.

Comment: Now how to merge local master with remote master

Comment: My aim is to change a file in the first commit and later push everythins using `push -f` to remote repo.

Comment: If all the commits of the master branch is done by yourself. You can just `push -f` to make your local master be your remote master. But I think you'd better backup the remote master by git branch master-backup origin/master first .